# Setting a login timeout when connecting to sql server with android

Tags: android, database, android-asynctask, database-connection, jtds

I'm using the jtds 1.2.7 driver to connect to an sql server express database on an android device. I deliberately set it up so that I would NOT be able to connect so I could try to set a custom timeout. No matter what I try, though, it always takes 3 minutes to timeout. Here is the code I use to open a connection:

```
String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.0.2.2:1433/Phone_Test;user=" + dUser + ";password=" + dPass + ";";

        //Calling instance of driver
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        //Getting connection
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(connString, dUser, dPass);
```

To set the timeout I've tried using

```
DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(5);
```

Before I try to establish the connection. I've also tried adding to the connection string:

```
String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.0.2.2:1433/Phone_Test;user=" + dUser + ";password=" + dPass + ";" + "loginTimeout=5;";
```

Nothing has worked so far. I am establishing this connection in a custom asynctask, so maybe an easier way would be to set some sort of timeout on the task? I don't want to use the .get() method because it blocks the UI thread. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I never solved this either, but I do have a good workaround. Using standard socket code, attempt to bind to the database port; the timeout is honoured here.

I've wrapped this up in a method thus:

```
public static final String DATABASE_ADDR = "10.0.2.2";
public static final int DATABASE_PORT = 1433;
public static final int TIMEOUT_MS = 2000; // 2 seconds

.
.
.

public boolean serverAvailable() {
    // First check if we have network connectivity
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo == null) {
        return false;
    }

    // Attempt to bind to database port 
    boolean available = false;
    SocketAddress sockAddr = new InetSocketAddress(DATABASE_ADDR, DATABASE_PORT);
    Socket sock = new Socket();

    // On timeout, SocketTimeoutException is thrown.
    try {
        sock.connect(sockAddr, TIMEOUT_MS);
        available = true;
    } catch(Exception e){}
    finally {
        try{
            sock.close();
        } catch(Exception e2) {}
    }

    return available;
}
```

It's possible the server could disappear in the instant between running this check and connecting to the database, but I can live with that.